# How to export a nested JSONArray to CSV?

Tags: java, arrays, json, api, csv

I have a JSONArray which contains multiple JSONObjects

```
[
   {
      "record":[
         {
            "timeStamp":"2018-10-11T05:36:51+00:00",
            "code":200,
            "text":"OK"
         },
         {
            "hostname":"qwe",
            "address":"192.168.1.1",
            "type":"A",
            "priority":"0",
            "ttl":"3600"
         },
         {
            "hostname":"www",
            "address":"test.com",
            "type":"CNAME",
            "priority":"0",
            "ttl":"3600"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "record":[
         {
            "timeStamp":"2018-10-11T05:36:52+00:00",
            "code":200,
            "text":"OK"
         },
         {
            "hostname":"rty",
            "address":"192.168.1.2",
            "type":"A",
            "priority":"0",
            "ttl":"300"
         },
         {
            "hostname":"*",
            "address":"test",
            "type":"CNAME",
            "priority":"0",
            "ttl":"3600"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I parse this JSONArray and export it as a CSV File.

This is what I have tried so far

```
    File file=new File("/home/administrator/Desktop/test.csv");
    String csv = jsonArray;
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
    System.out.println("CSV created.");
```

My desired output is

```
timeStamp,code,text,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl
    2018-10-11T05:36:51+00:00,200,OK,qwe,192.168.1.1,A,0,300,www,test.com,CNAME,0,3600
    2018-10-11T05:36:52+00:00,200,OK,rty,192.168.1.2,A,0,300,*,test,CNAME,0,3600
```

Is it possible to have an output like this given the JSONArray above?

Comment: Hey can you tell me what JSON Parsing lib you are using so I know what to use? :)

Comment: Hi @Rab I'm using org.json in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late respond was bashing my keyboard for the past 30 minutes but I finally got it done, here is the code.

```
public static String getCSVData() throws IOException, JSONException {
    Path jsonFile = Paths.get("json");
    String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(jsonFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.trim());
    List<List<String>> jsonArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        List<String> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray record = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("record");
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < record.length(); i2++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = record.getJSONObject(i2);
            if (i2 == 0) {
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("timeStamp").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("code").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("text").toString());
            } else {
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("hostname").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("address").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("type").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("priority").toString());
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject.get("ttl").toString());
            }
        }
        jsonArrays.add(jsonObjects);
    }
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("timeStamp,code,text,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl\n");
    for(List<String> arrays : jsonArrays){
        stringBuilder.append(StringUtils.join(arrays, ",")).append("\n");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
}
```

To explain the code first I looped over the first Array and then get the jsonObject of the first JSONArray and then get the jsonArray named "record" from the JsonObject I have gotten by looping over the first JSONArray and then loop over record and get all the items and save them into an ArrayList. and join them via StringUtils which is provided by JDK.

if you want to write it to file use this

```
Files.write(Paths.get("YOUR CSV FILE"), getCSVData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

all the code I used are provided by JDK and org.json.

after we print out getCSVDate(); the output is:

```
timeStamp,code,text,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl,hostname,address,type,priority,ttl
2018-10-11T05:36:51+00:00,200,OK,qwe,192.168.1.1,A,0,3600,www,test.com,CNAME,0,3600
2018-10-11T05:36:52+00:00,200,OK,rty,192.168.1.2,A,0,300,*,test,CNAME,0,3600
```

Comment: Hi @Rab, my json is coming from the other class which collects the api response. This is how I create my class for exporting:

   public void getCSVData(JSONArray jsonArray){
}

How can I initialize the json that is coming from the other class?

Comment: yes, you can turn the JSON into a string and then make a parameter on the method. `public static String getCSVData(String jsonData)`

Comment: do I have to change the line `Path jsonFile = Paths.get("json");`?

Comment: yes you have to. remove that line and change this to `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);` if you want to put the String in `String getCSVData(String jsonData)`

Comment: I'm getting this error `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.` I change it to `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        List<List<String>> jsonArrays = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Don't change the List, are you sure jsonData is a string? can you print out jsonData and see if its the same as JSON in the question?

Comment: I think I fixed it. But where do I put the line `Files.write(Paths.get("YOUR CSV FILE"), getCSVData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181658/discussion-between-rab-and-lanz-joshua).